# csrf_token() is empty in l5-swagger and couldn't do any request except GET request

Tags: php, laravel, swagger, csrf-token

csrf_token() is empty in l5-swagger and couldn't do any request except GET because the header is missing and always getting 419 error code

I have tried to request it from postman and it works. but in swagger it didn't. I have taken a look from this link ([laravel 5 csrf_token value is Empty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35216586/laravel-5-csrf-token-value-is-empty)) but I still have no idea how to solve my problem.

How can I get the csrf_token inside my l5-swagger view?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you should try to add this in /routes/web.php

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'web'], function () {
    Route::get('api/documentation', '\L5Swagger\Http\Controllers\SwaggerController@api')->name('l5swagger.api');
});
```

so you can add the web middleware on l5-swagger route

hope it helps

Comment: Wow, thanks! It works, but can you explain more about the code?

Comment: if you add web middleware, then laravel will know that u need csrf token and csrf_token() value will not be empty

Comment: Ah, I see. Thanks for your input

Comment: This is giving the error of configuration missing

Comment: unfortunately, this does not work for me with Laravel 8.x, see my answer if you are in the same boat

Answer (score 4):

None of these worked for me in Laravel 8.70.1.

What worked for me was to disable the EnsureFrontendRequestsAreStateful::class in both my local and dev (no public access) environments. Then in my deployment process (TeamCity & OctoDeploy) to both staging and production, the commented EnsureFrontendRequestsAreStateful::class is uncommented.

Swagger is disabled as part of the deployment process to both the staging and prod environments. If you are building a SPA you need the EnsureFrontendRequestsAreStateful class.

In summary, disabling the EnsureFrontendRequestsAreStateful::class should solve the problem, but make sure you put it back in both your staging and production environments.

File to edit is in /app/Http/Kernel.php

```
   //\Laravel\Sanctum\Http\Middleware\EnsureFrontendRequestsAreStateful::class,
            'throttle:60,1',
            \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
            \App\Http\Middleware\AuthGates::class,


        ],
```

Answer (score 3):

For Laravel 8.x the solution with Routes did not work for me.

Instead i modified the file `config/l5-swagger.php`

you have to add multiple entries to `defaults[routes][middleware][api]`. By default this entry should be empty.

To fix the CSRF-Validation you have to add:

```php
...

'api' => [
    \App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
    \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
    \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
    \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
    \App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
    \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
],

...
```

After that just clear the config cache with

```sh
php artisan config:cache
```

And you are good to go!

Comment: For some reason this does not work for me. I am using latest version of laravel and L5-swagger

Comment: What is your result?

Comment: It was  419 error code. I have fixed it by putting it in the exception list. However I am not sure that this is the best practice.

Comment: that pretty much will disable the CSRF-Errors for Laravel.

Did you see the CSRF-Token when trying out the API via Swagger-UI? Something like:

  -H 'X-CSRF-TOKEN: OmyttElThbpda9aCWnAu2LYR2NOOwDAfdfdsfasdf'

Also: please make sure you are using the *api*-routes, not the web-routes!

Comment: For anyone having this same issue, while running on development using `php artisan serve` and using the OA\Server annotation with L5_SWAGGER_CONST_HOST ensure that this value is consistent with what serve is doing, for example, http://localhost:8000 and http://127.0.0.1:8000 are different